# link static lib in eclipse cdt

Tags: c++, eclipse, static-libraries

I am sorry!  I have googled this a lot and cannot find an answer!  It's dumb I know.

I cannot link in static libraries(*.a) in eclipse cdt.  I listed them all in Project->Settings-> GCC C++ linker -> Libraries.  I used the absolute path to make sure I had the lib correct... and i get:

cannot find -l/usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.a

I am sure it's stupid whatever I am doing wrong :(

Edit -- and i should mention i am linking the libraries at run time...

Comment: You can specify the full path for libs in gcc by prepending ':'. So in your case that would be '-l:/usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.a', or add ':/usr/...' to the libraries in eclipse. But the convention of prefix 'lib' and adding search paths is there for a reason, so better use absolute paths only if _really_ necessary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I remember having a similar issue way back when I was compiling our code under linux (coming from a windows background) and if I recall correctly specifying the absolute path to the static lib also didn't work.

Are you aware that to link to "libboost_date_time.a", you need to specify "boost_date_time" without the "lib" and the ".a"? In my case that solved the problem. /usr/local/lib should be on your path in any case AFAIR.

Comment: I did try not dropping the ".a" and I still get the same error??

Comment: @Ralph.... Got it... needed to set up each dir (-L) and then each library without the "lib" or the ".a"  thanks...

Comment: If you have a direct path to the library, you can link to it without the `-l` flag (e.g., `gcc foo.cpp /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.a`)

Comment: John Bartholomew - you can't do that in Eclipse (at least not via *Paths and Symbols -> Libraries*. Eclipse still adds the `-l`).

Comment: I tried this method and it failed.  Not sure why.  The other answer works for me.

Answer (score 16):

Static libraries or archives are just a collection of object files.

Add the archive as *Other Objects* under *C/C++ Build -> Settings -> C++ Linker -> Miscellaneous*:

[image]

Some folks cry bloody murder over specifying a full pathname. I find it works in practice (unlike theory at times), and its no worse than breaking the *path* and *filename*, and then specifying them with `-L` and `-l`. And did I mention it actually works in practice...

Comment: I've tried that, it seems not to work. I've done this with the newest mongodb drivers. Is there something i've got to be careful ? Like not having the ".so" libs in a include path?

Comment: This is probably the best answer for the OP, as his archive is not prefixed by `lib`. It worked a treat for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much!  I tried the (-l) and (-L) method, and it fails.  Too much headache.  Your way works.

Answer (score 7):

I had the similar problem when adding the libs in the `C/C++ General->Paths & Symbols` configuration screen.

Instead on the `C/C++ Build -> settings` screen under `GCC C++ Linker / Libraries` I added the library name without lib and `.a` in Libraries (-l) and adding the path in Libraries search path `(-L)`. This solved my problem

Comment: @256: Probably best to start a new question if this answer didn't help.

Comment: thx. removing the "lib", in addition to ".a" was the missing link!