# Eclipse-CDT/C++: Undefined reference-errors although right .o-files are created and passed to the linker

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, linker-errors, undefined-reference

At first: I am *not* using an already compiled library.

Here's the situation: I've got a C++ project in eclipse CDT that has a folder structure like this:

```
project
  somefoldername
    src
    include
  library
    src
    include
```

somefoldername/src and library/src are defined as source folders and somefoldername/include as well as library/include are defined as include folders (under C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols, which also affects the compilers -I option).

The "library" folder contains the source code of a library used by my own code (which can be found in "somefolder"). Well, compiling of the whole project works fine, but linking crashes with a whole bunch of "undefined reference" errors in the library's source.

The undefined reference errors occur, although *.o-files are created in which the missing functions should be found - and also are passed to the linker afterwards.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Updated to current configuration and the attempts to solve the problem.

**Edit2:** The accepted answer helped me out a bit, but the biggest problem seemed to be the "linking everything at once"-policy followed by eclipse. I went to [autoconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) and built the library first, before linking it to the main application. Although it's more work, it's a cleaner approach.

Comment: Q: Have you resolved this yet?

Comment: Finally, yes. I went through it, together with the author of the library. Some errors came from definitions the library expected to be made by the using source code (which made your point 1) partly right), but few strange things still remained. So I went from the ordinary GCC tool chain to autoconf and built the library seperately, befor linking it to the whole thing. This somehow did the trick. Probably linking all .o-files at once leads to problems. So it wasn't the "extern C"-part, but your first guess solved a part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three possibilities:

1) The "undefined" symbols aren't actually in your library

```
 This is unlikely, but you can verify using the "nm" Linux command
```

2) You aren't setting the library search path ("dash-big-L") correctly in Eclipse

- [link static lib in eclipse cdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952403/link-static-lib-in-eclipse-cdt)

  ... or ...

  3) Perhaps you built the library with "C" linkage, but your program is using C++ linkage (or vice versa).  If you're using the "C" (gcc") compiler, or have any "*.c" source files, then make sure *all* functions have prototypes in your .h header, and all prototypes use "extern "C"" as appropriate:

  & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: 1) They are in the library 2) That would be my guess. How should it be set? 3) The library contains c code, but I'm not using it directly and it is correctly handled inside the library as far as i know.

Comment: As I mentioned above, i _do not use a compiled library_. The "library" folder contains source code, so the link under 2) doesn't help much, does it?

Comment: If the library contains C code ... and your program is using C++ ... and you haven't clearly defined *each* global and function name with "extern C" ... then the problem is curtain 3).  Q: Are .o files being generated for your "library" source"?  Q: do the external symbols have C or C++ linkage (you can use "nm" on your .o files to see)?  Q: Are you including these .o files (explicitly including each .o file) in your link?

Comment: I didn't go to the whole source of the library, but the usages of the c source I discovered clearly wraps the includes into an "extern C". Yes, .o files are genereated for the library source as I wrote above. All the .o files are passed to the linker, as I wrote above. I have to admit that I can't handle the nm command, as I don't lern anything of the documentation and it gives thousands of unreadable lines. Obviously mangled function names, if that is what you're asking for.

Comment: OK: if "nm *.o|less" shows mangled (C++) names, then it sounds like "extern "C"" is *NOT working (at least not when you build your \*.o source).  Q: Are the "extern C" function prototypes and variable declarations in your .h header files (and NOT locally, in \*.c/.cpp source)?  Q: Are you #includ'ing these header files in *ALL source code (e.g. both "main.cpp" as well as "myfunctionsrc.c")???

Comment: @aRestless: please do this: 1) Choose one "unresolved" link error as an example, 2) See if the corresponding .o file was built, 3) run "nm XXX.o | less" on the .o file for the symbol, 3) Determine if the symbol in the .o file is mangled (C++) or not (C linkage), 4) See if the .h header has "extern C" or not, 5) See if the header is included in both XXX.cpp and your application source or not, 6) Post back the results (cut/paste the link error and the "extern C" declaration).  OK?