# I got an error library not found , if library dosnt exists under usr/lib

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have 3rd parties libraries that don't placed under "/usr/lib".
I defined their path in eclipse library search path .
The project compile and linkage well, but when i run project i got exception that library doesn't found.
if i copy the 3rd party library to "/usr/lib" than it run ok.

I believe that this is path issue (i am new to cpp), how do i configure this in eclipse ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since it's crashing during runtime, you are linking against dynamic libraries (libWhatever.so), so you have to add your library path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Otherwise, you could force the linker to link statically to static libraries (libWhatever.a), using the `-static` flag.

Comment: I am sure that this is the correct answer. the problem is that i use eclipse cdt and i dont know how to configure it in eclipse-cdt

Comment: But why don't you just link statically, to avoid tons of headaches? Check the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952403/link-static-lib-in-eclipse-cdt

Comment: sorry , for my ignorance. i am new to cpp. can i link statistically even if i have only so?

Comment: Uh, OK, that is quite unpleasant. In this case, you definitely need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Eclipse is smart enough to do this for you, though. See here: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_run_env.htm