# Libcrypto++ shared libraries missing

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries, ubuntu-14.04, crypto++

I somehow managed to install the `libcrypto++` library on `Ubuntu 14.04`. Now, I have a project in `Eclipse CDT` which I would like to create an executable of and make it independently run on other linux flavors and windows(being ambitious here).

I am using the executable in the `Debug` folder of eclipse to run my program.

I get the following error when I run try to execute the program on any other machine

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto++.so
```

Can anyone tell me:

1. How I can get rid of this error ?
2. How can I create a cross platform executable in the Eclipse IDE ?

Comment: Anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> I get the following error when I run try to execute the program on any other machine
>
> error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto++.so
>
> How I can get rid of this error ?
> ```

Eclipse is a pain in the butt at times. Effectively, it tries to use the shared object (`libcrypto++.so`) whether you want it or not.

To work around this, specify `libcrypptopp.a` as an additional object file. Archives are a collection of object files, so they can be used interchangeably with an object file.

You enter it at *Other Objects* under *C/C++ Build -> Settings -> C++ Linker -> Miscellaneous*. You can see a screen capture of where to enter `libcrypptopp.a` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21919306/608639) Stack Overflow answer.

Do *not* list Crypto++ in the library sections of eclipse.

---

> How can I create a cross platform executable in the Eclipse IDE ?

Not sure what you mean, but you will need to compile Crypto++ for each platform you plan on supporting. That includes x86, x64, ARM, ARMv7 and MIPS.

Comment: By Cross platform I meant cross OS(windows and linux). In any case your solution solved the problem and I can now run the executable in almost all linux distributions. Thanks !